# Visual Blend 2015 not showing Edit adaptive triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I'm viewing this artical: http://mobileprogrammerblog.azurewebsites.net/2015/09/14/universal-windows-10-application-with-tailored-design-part-2/

In the Step 8 [image]- NOW ADD NEW STATE AND NAME IT “PORTRAITSTATE” AS SHOWN BELOW:

I can' see the **Edit adaptive triggers** button.
Does my Visual Studio missing some part ?
This is my screen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you see how in that tutorial you're following how one of the first things they tell you to do is create a blank app project for **Windows Universal**?

Where as your project from your second screen shot is obviously a **WPF** project...

Which wouldn't support Adaptive Triggers, hence why you don't have the option. Hope this helps, cheers.